# Getting Log File Lines Within Timespan

Tags: linux, sed, grep, redhat

I have the following code that only works when manually substituting the $NOW and $THEN variables in the sed command.  If I echo the sed command all variables output correctly.

I'm trying to get the lines within the newest log file only for the last 60 seconds and then count those that match my search string.

```
SYSFile="ls -1t /home/SPC/Log"
NewestFile=$($SYSFile | grep SYS | head -1)
NOW="$(date "+%m\/%d %H:%M:%S")"
THEN="$(date --date="60 seconds ago" "+%m\/%d %H:%M:%S")"
sed -n '/$THEN/ , /$NOW/p' $NewestFile | grep "Processing inbound for unit" | wc -l`
```

Below is a snippet from the log file showing the date format that I am using.

```
[07/16 08:35:17.998]
[07/16 08:35:17.998]
[07/16 08:35:17.998]
[07/16 08:35:17.998]
[07/16 08:35:17.998]
[07/16 08:35:17.999]
[07/16 08:35:17.999]
[07/16 08:35:18.176]
[07/16 08:35:18.176]
[07/16 08:35:18.176]
[07/16 08:35:18.176]
[07/16 08:35:18.176]
[07/16 08:35:18.176]
[07/16 08:35:18.176]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `awk`

```
NewestFile=$($SYSFile | grep SYS | head -1)
NOW="$(date "+%m\/%d %H:%M:%S")"
THEN="$(date --date="60 seconds ago" "+%m\/%d %H:%M:%S")"
awk -v s="$THEN" e="$NOW" 's,e' $NewestFile | grep "Processing inbound for unit" | wc -l
```

Or maybe shorten some

```
awk -v s="$THEN" e="$NOW" 's,e {if (/Processing inbound for unit) a++} END {print a}' $NewestFile
```

Or you can do this:

```
awk -v s="$(date --date="60 seconds ago" "+%m\/%d %H:%M:%S")" e="$(date "+%m\/%d %H:%M:%S")" 's,e {if (/Processing inbound for unit) a++} END {print a}' $NewestFile
```

---

This:

```
date --date="60 seconds ago" "+%m\/%d %H:%M:%S"
```

can be shorten some to

```
date -d -60sec "+%m\/%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: I get the following error: `awk: warning: escape sequence `\/' treated as plain `/'
awk: e=07\/15 19:20:43
awk:     ^ backslash not last character on line`

Comment: The date is formatted like this: [07/15 14:12:13.682].  I don't care about the milliseconds.

Comment: option 1 gives me the following error: `awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `s,e' for reading (No such file or directory)`

Comment: It is the "\" in the date that gives you problem.  I just copied you format.  Try `NOW="$(date "+%m/%d %H:%M:%S")"`

Comment: When I run `awk -v s="$(date --date="60 seconds ago" "+%m/%d %H %M %S")" e="$(date "+%m/%d %H %M %S")" 's,e {if (/Processing inbound for unit) a++} END {print a}' $NewestFile` I get the response: **awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `s,e {if (/Processing inbound for unit) a++} END {print a}' for reading (No such file or directory)**

Comment: The following code is now producing the total line numbers of the file `awk -v s="$(date -d -60sec "+%m/%d %H:%M:%S")" -v e="$(date "+%m/%d %H:%M:%S")" 's,e {if ("Processing inbound for unit") a++} END {print a}' $NewestFile`

Comment: The following returns all lines with the search phrase, disregarding the time window. `awk -v s="$(date -d -60sec "+%m/%d %H:%M:%S")" -v e="$(date "+%m/%d %H:%M:%S")" 's,e' $NewestFile | grep "Processing inbound for unit" | wc -l`